# Query behavior when the warehouse fails

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use snowflake for turning out if it can use for DWH, and I am concern with the query behavior when the warehouse somehow fails.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-considerations.html#multi-cluster-warehouses-improve-concurrency
According to the above page, if the minimum cluster is set to higher than 1, it helps ensure availability and continuity.
I have questions about it.

1.If we set it to 1 and the warehouse fails, the proceeded query come to fail?
2.If we set it to 2 or more and a cluster of the warehouse fails, the proceeded query come to fail and start automatically by another cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a warehouse fails, a new warehouse is automatically started and the query is retired. In the 6 years at my prior job that we ran snowflake, there was less that a dozen times where we experienced warehouse failure.

It was often around releases being rolled out. One thing that does happen on failure is the release is pushed back. So we noticed blips in our processing rate, or increased total time, and during the trouble periods the query profile might show 1-3 tabs of query plan, for each retry.

At least one of those outages was a failure to bring up new warehouses, class of problem, and in that incident, I don't think we where impacted as we have stuff just always running.

A side note also is you get billed for those failures, so that can bite if you are doing large computations and it fails and retries. We have had refunds (of the extra cost) when we can show there was a cost increase due to a known failure event.

But if you are looking at run Medium and smaller warehouses those normally start same second, so you might not notice a "failure" but if you are running a really large instance size, it can take longer to bring that capacity online.